# php jquery div refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have on my page (`page1.php`) a div called `result` that updates when you click a link with the `loadlink` id. It sends a url along to `page2.php` The script is:

```
$(function() {
  $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#result").load($(this).data('url'));
  });
});
```

I want it so it also updates another div called `crimes` after this runs, with data from a url `page3.php`. How can i change the code to do this?

Comment: A correction: you state `when you click a link with the loadlink id`. The period notation denotes that you are looking for elements with the `loadlink` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function of the `.load()` function to run another AJAX request once this one completes:

```
$(function() {
    $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#result").load($(this).data('url'), function () {
            $('#crimes').load('page3.php');
        });
    });
});
```

Note: if the second AJAX request does not rely on the first then you can run them simultaneously (just call them one after another and they will update the DOM whenever then return successfully). You will not know which one will come back first however, that's the usefulness of the callback function, you will know that one has completed before sending the next request.

Comment: This is correct if you don't want `#crimes` to load until after `#result` loads. It's unclear from the question exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Actually the OP stated: `after this runs`, but I was adding my note when you posted your comment, so I too am not totally sure what the OP wanted.

Comment: I want the crimes div to update after the result one has been updated. I tried this code but can't get it working.

Comment: There's not much to it: http://api.jquery.com/load/. You can add a callback function to your first `.load()` call that will be run after the first AJAX request is complete. Inside that function you can run another `.load()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another load() to the click function.

```
$(function() {
  $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").load($(this).data('url'));
    $("#crimes").load('page3.php');
  });
});
```